# Как создать action на кнопку в navigationbar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

у меня есть 2 кнопки в navigationbar, они расположены в tabbarviewcontroller как показано на рисунке ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обращаться к этим кнопкам?
Вот допустим при нажатии чтобы image на кнопке менялся

Comment: сделай кастомный navigation controller, что-то вроде CustomNavigationController. И инить свои нав контроллеры этим сабкласом

Answer (score 0):

Создайте `IBOutlet` как для любого другого элемента и на нужные события меняйте image.

Comment: Я бы с радостью так сделать, только видите у navigation bar и tab bar нет контроллеров, поэтому когда я тяну к какому либо другому, то action добавляется, а связь нет

Comment: @Marshall нужно смотреть что в проекте. Сейчас как на кофейной гуще можно гадать..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить эти кнопки (RU, KZ) не в сториборде (ui-редакторе), а в коде в методе viewDidLoad() вашего вьюконтроллера.

```
func setBarButtonItems () {
  let ruButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ru_icon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onRuButtonTapped(_:)))

  let kzButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "kz_icon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onKzButtonItemTapped(_:)))

  var barItems = [ruButton, kzButton]
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barItems
}

@objc func onRuButtonTapped (_ sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
  sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage("active_ru_icon"), for: .plain, barMetrics: .default)
}
@objc func onKzButtonItemTapped (_ sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
  sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage("active_kz_icon"), for: .plain, barMetrics: .default)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  setBarButtonItems()
}
```